# Are these test cases correct?

Tags: math, probability

While working on the google foobar problems, I ran into one with the following prompt:

Professor Boolean, a notorious mad scientist, just found out his precious rabbit specimen has escaped! He rushes to call his security minions on the lab phone. However, the rabbit escapee hacked the phone to speed her escape! She left a sign with the following clues: Each digit that is dialed has to be a number that can be reached by a knight chess piece from the last digit dialed - that is, you must move precisely 2 spaces in one direction, and then 1 space in a perpendicular direction to dial the next correct number. You can dial any number you want to start with, but subsequent numbers must obey the knight's move rule.

The lab phone has the numbers arranged in the following way: 1, 2, 3 in the first row; 4, 5, 6 in the second row; 7, 8, 9 in the third row; and blank, 0, blank in the fourth row.

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
  0
```

For example, if you just dialed a 1, the next number you dial has to be either a 6 or an 8. If you just dialed a 6, the next number must be a 1 or 7.

Professor Boolean wants you to find out how many different phone numbers he can dial under these conditions. Write a function called answer(x, y, z) that computes the number of phone numbers one can dial that start with the digit x, end in the digit y, and consist of z digits in total. Output this number as a string representing the number in base-10.

x and y will be digits from 0 to 9. z will be between 1 and 100, inclusive.

Test cases

Inputs:
    (int) x = 6
    (int) y = 2
    (int) z = 5
Output:
    (string) "6"

Inputs:
    (int) x = 1
    (int) y = 5
    (int) z = 100
Output:
    (string) "0"

Inputs:
    (int) x = 3
    (int) y = 7
    (int) z = 1
Output:
    (string) "0"

---

I feel that the first test case is wrong because after drawing out the decision tree the only numbers I find are possible are 61672, 67272, 67292, 67672, which is only four.
Is there something I'm misinterpreting or missing about this problem?

Comment: You've missed 60492 and 60672

Comment: I was under the impression that since the problem stated "If you just dialed a 6, the next number must be a 1 or 7" that blanks would not be considered valid moves

Comment: The problem description contains a mistake. If you just dialed 6 the next number can be 1, 7 or 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the test case is wrong, but the statement

> If you just dialed a 6, the next number must be a 1 or 7.

is wrong. Not being able to get from 6 to 0 makes the problem not make any sense. As to your comment, blanks aren't valid moves, but what does that have to do with 6 -> 0 being valid?

```
1 2 3  
4 5 6  
7 8 9  
  0
```

Obviously 6 -> 0 is a valid move, no blanks involved.